# Twitter API geo

Tags: twitterapi-python

I am really new to this and I am trying to use Twitter's API to get geo information.  It seems pretty straight forward.  Enter Latitude/Longitude and the distance to search from this point in either mi. or km but I don't know how/where I am supposed to enter my API key or what format/order it is supposed to be in; where it is supposed to be located, etc... here is sample:

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?q=%20&geocode=37.781157%2C-122.398720%2C10mi

so where do I put my credentials and in what order etc... I just can't find any info.

As always, all help is greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You can't submit credentials via a URL. With python you can use this library: 
[TwitterAPI](https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI)

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
SEARCH_TERM = 'pizza'
GEOCODE = '37.781157,-122.398720,10mi'
api = TwitterAPI(<consumer key>, <consumer secret>, <access token key>, <access token secret>)
r = api.request('search/tweets', {'q':SEARCH_TERM, 'geocode':GEOCODE})
for item in r:
    print(item['text'] if 'text' in item else item)
```